# conditional regex in python string matching

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

```
pattern=re.compile(r'item (?(1)2|3)')
n=re.findall(pattern, 'item 2 item 3')
```

The output is:
['item 2', 'item 3']
But i want it to be just item 2 in case it's present in the string or item 3 in case item 2 is not present.
An explanation of my error along with the solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import re

itemlist = ["pickles", "item 2", "item3"]
text = "item 3 item 2"

for item in itemlist:
    if re.search(item, text):
        print (item)
        break
```

Iterating over the ordered list, if a match is found break out.

```
item 2
```

Comment: Actually i want it like this:- if item 2 is present: match only item 2, else: match only item 3. Therefore i need to use conditional regex

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
if bool(re.search('item 2', word)):
    n=re.findall('item 2', word)
else:
    n=re.findall('item 3', word)
```

Comment: Yes but without the if else clause, with conditional regex.